Why is the power set not considered a filter?
A class $\mathcal{F}$ of nonempty subsets of a set $X$ is said to be a filter, iff, the next three properties are satisfied:
$X\in\mathcal{F}$.
For all sets $A_1,...,A_n\in\mathcal{F}$, it holds that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\in\mathcal{F}$.
For every subset $B\subseteq X$ which contains some $A\in\mathcal{F}$,
it holds that $B\in\mathcal{F}$.
We require sets in $\mathcal{F}$ to be nonempty to avoid the power set being a filter, why is that so? Why is the power set not considered a filter?

This comment supplies a very soft answer: we want the notion of filter to capure the idea of a set being "large" in some sense appropriate to the work at hand. The empty set is unlikely to be "large" in useful contexts.
